# Generating a random number in C gives me the same output every time

Tags: c

I'm having some issues getting a random int.
I need to run this function in a for loop, but every time I run the program does generate a random output until the next time i run it.
Sometimes even running multiples times the output is the same.

```
char gerarMesa(){
          srand(time(NULL));
          int n = rand() % 5;
          return (char) n + 65;
 }
```

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdyYM.png)

Comment: `srand` should only be called once for the lifetime of the program. Not every time the function is called.

Comment: Ok i think that did it

Comment: What do you think `srand` does?  If you understand it, your program will work.  If you do not understand it, you should read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are probably calling this function in a tight loop, it's possible that your `time` function is returning the same result for each call to `gerarMesa`. Since you are re-initializing the seed with the same number each time you request a random number, you are getting the same result.

Try only calling `srand` once, at the beginning of your `main` function.